# A single word meaning to abide in a place for a long time

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Can anybody give me a single word meaning to abide in a place for long time?

I'm thinking in the context of "to remain in prison" (or elsewhere, against one's will).

Comment: Did you consider *to reside* or to *inhabit* ?

Comment: @nicholas, I'm *rotting* here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Languish" seems to be a popular word to evoke that incarceration feeling.

Comment: "Languish" does indeed imply incarceration and/or time-wasting, but why do you say "**that** incarceration feeling"? OP doesn't mention any such, and to my mind the word **abide** has overtones of (pleasant) time well (or restfully) spent. Who ever *abided* in a dungeon?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - See OP's comment here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23375/a-single-word-meaning-to-abide-in-a-place-for-a-long-time/23388#23388

Comment: oic. Well, OP should have either said that in the original question, or at least edited it in later. We're not all psychic, and some of us don't read every comment on every answer before chipping in.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Agreed.

Comment: Every cloud has a silver lining. I will doubtless be awarded some new SE badge for altruism, having just done the donkey work for OP myself.

Answer (score 3):

[settle](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/settle) and [dwell](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dwell)

have implications of a "permanent residence" - which might be a slightly longer time than what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

What is the context in which you are using the word? Maybe 'linger' is the word.

Comment: well, to remain in prison or against someones will...

Comment: @nicholas: _Abide_ sounds very voluntary to me.

Answer (score 2):

Sojourn? As in "I am a sojourner like my forefathers"

Comment: OP specifically said "for a long time", but *to sojourn* usually implies the opposite. Including Psalm 39:12, where the prayer also says he's only a "guest" (i.e. - not a native or long-term resident).

Answer (score 0):

Bound - "He was bound to this place by responsibility"

Imprisoned