# Antonym of nomad

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

What do you call someone who isn't a nomad? Someone who has a fixed abode.

I tried a google search, but [this post](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_antonym_of_nomad) and [this one](https://m.reddit.com/r/literature/comments/20nygq/are_there_no_suitable_antonyms_for_wanderer_or/) had some rather disappointing answers.

Comment: Why not _Sedentary_ ?

Comment: Related: [Single word meaning 'to remain in place for a long time](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/23375/8019).

Comment: There are dozens of synonyms for *nomad* but no real antonyms. Why? I presume because we don't need that term. Someone who is a nomad, or a rover, or a vagabond, or any of the others, is the one being talked about, while everyone else is not so interesting to us to require a special term.

Comment: I would tend to think *settled* as in a *population of land settlers* as opposed to a *nomadic population*.

Comment: @Robusto Mankind's natural condition, surely, is that of a nomad. Becoming *settled* is a condition which arrived later. It is us who are odd, the nomads of the Kalahari perfectly normal!

Comment: @WS2: Then why do we have so many words for the one and not the other? Surely this is evidence that we don't think of ourselves in the way you suggest. Perhaps we did roam in hunter-gatherer groups at some point in the distant past, but since we started writing words down the balance has shifted very much in the opposite direction.

Comment: @WS: of course, we are the odd ones. But then again, the language we use today evolved amongst us "weirdos", so we made a special word for the normal folks. It's for the same reason we have a lot of words for "coloured" people, whereas it's the "white" folks that are the melanine-deficient stray from the normal.

Comment: What were the thesaurus suggestions that were so disappointing? Were any in the right direction and why?

Comment: You know you've been coding too much when: you read this title as "antonym of *monad*" and so your first idea for a single-word answer is "comprehensible".

Comment: Must be *mad*...

Comment: A *couch potato*.

Comment: Not quite an antonym, but someone who lives in a city is an *urbanite*.

Comment: Here's a try: Agoraphobic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The antonym of nomad is ***nonnomad***. It is mentioned in *[dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nonnomad)* also.

[image]

Examples from *Google Books*:

> ...“fixed abode of the nomad (Beduin), whom death transforms into a **permanent settler (nonnomad)** (*mugim*) for all eternity”
>
> <sub>*The Spiritual Background of Early Islam* by M.M. Bravmann</sub>
>
> ---
>
> This represented the first time “Uyghur” entered official use to refer to the Türki-speaking **nonnomad** population of southern Xinjiang.
>
> <sub>*Xinjiang: China's Muslim Borderland* by S. Frederick Starr</sub>

Note: The hyphenated form ***non-nomad*** looks like more common based on [Google Books result](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22nonnomad%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=CH5wVeinFISxyATqmYHYDQ#q=%22non-nomad%22&safe=off&tbm=bks&start=0).

Answer (score 23):

If you're speaking of historical populations, you might use the word "***settler***".

Comment: I believe this is the right answer. A **settler** intends on making a specific location his home for the foreseeable future, which is the closest thing to a **nomad**, who implicitly accepts the fact that he _has_ no home.

Comment: Obviously this answer makes more sense than *nonnomad*... which my spell checker refuses to recognize. I don't care if it is "mentioned" in a dictionary, it only reflects that people have coined that term because they were too dumb to think up "settler" or "dweller" or "resident" etc.

Answer (score 12):

A ***[resident](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/resident)*** may convey the idea of someone who lives permanently in the same place:

> - One who resides in a particular place permanently or for an extended period.
>     (AHD)

or an  ***[inhabitant:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inhabitant)***

> - One that inhabits a place, *especially as a permanent resident*: the inhabitants of a fishing village; snakes, lizards, and other inhabitants of the desert.

Answer (score 9):

@Eilia's comment pretty much hits the mark. According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sedentary) *sedentary* means (among others):

> staying or living in one place instead of moving to different places

Or more pronounced yet:

> 1: not migratory:  settled (sedentary birds) (sedentary civilizations)

Aside from *sedentary* the antonyms and near antonyms listed for [migrant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/migrant) might be interesting as well.

Comment: For me that's the right answer. I remember of my teachers (when i was in school) saying something like : "The first civilizations started with the nomad people adopting a sedentary lifestyle"

Comment: But would you describe yourself as a *sedentary person* to explain that you are not a nomad? http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/sedentary.

Comment: @Josh61 If asked to explain I'd much rather say I'm not a nomad avoiding any possible weirdness. But if asked for an antonym I'd stay with *sedentary*.

Answer (score 7):

The opposite of *a nomad* is *a dweller*.

Comment: Perhaps _indweller_ would be better?  Viz. "a person who inhabits a particular place" (Wordnet).

Comment: Typically, *dweller* would be preceded by a noun indicating the type of place where the dweller dwells (forest-dweller, cave-dweller, mountain-dweller, swamp-dweller, tree-dweller, city-dweller, stackexchange-dweller, etc).

Answer (score 5):

Here in Ireland, there is a community which is traditionally nomadic: they are known by various names, but usually as The Travellers (in the UK, they are known as Irish Travellers, and recognised as an indigenous minority ethnic group). RTÉ, the state broadcaster, will refer to “members of the Travelling community”. The rest of us, by contrast, are known as the Settled community. (We are not called *settlers*, which to me invokes images of arriving at a place and settling there. I didn’t *settle* here: I was *born* here.)

Comment: "Settler" similarly evokes in me thoughts of British settlers in Australia, or similar phenomena happening nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

To actually contrast a resident from someone who roams, maybe someone who used to roam, you could use the following...

Someone who has a fixed abode has **[settled down](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/settle)**

> [NO OBJECT] Adopt a more steady or secure style of life, especially in a permanent job and home:
>
> *one day I will settle down and raise a family*

You can simply call them **settled**.

> [WITH ADVERBIAL OF PLACE] Make one’s permanent home somewhere:

---

Informally, if a nomad stops roaming, you can say that they've **dropped anchor**.

Answer (score 3):

I initially agreed with [Tarok's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/250379/45284), but from the [Wikipedia page on "sedentary lifestyle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedentary_lifestyle):

> *This article is about the medical term. For the anthropologic concept, see [sedentism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedentism).*

So perhaps the term is *sedentic*?

Consider this usage from the front-inside-cover of *Origins and History of Jats and Other Allied Nomadic Tribes of India*:

[image: Primarily endogamous communities, calling themselves as Jatt, Jat, Getae or Zutt, lived predominantly in large parts of norther and north-western India and in southern and eastern parts, now in Pakistan. They were either sedentic farmers or nomadic pastoralists.]

Answer (score 2):

In the animal kingdom we would describe a creature, like the coral polyp, that didn't choose to roam as **sessile**.  I doubt there is a noun form however.

Comment: I have seen the word 'sessor' used, but it may just be a coinage (from the Latin) by one writer, IIRC L. Sprague deCamp.

Answer (score 1):

Not a true antonym, but you may be able to use *farmer*. By definition, a farmer must stay in the area to tend to their crops.

A nomad is someone that by definition must travel to gather food. A farmer does not need to travel since their food is grown where they live.

Comment: Finding food is secondary; a nomad is someone who has no permanent home.

Comment: I rather like this, in context. You could even use "villager"

Comment: @James "villager" sounds like an antonym of "werewolf" http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mafia_%28party_game%29

Answer (score 1):

[Homebody](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/homebody) may suit your needs. Of course, one need not be too narrow about their definition of "home" here. After all, the word encompasses even the unadventurous types.

Answer (score 0):

I find nomad tribes and settled tribes in Pons German-English (sesshaft - settled tribes).

Comment: So what do you call someone who has a fixed abode?

Answer (score -1):

Another option might be a *local*.

Comment: Locals do not necessarily have fixed abodes. They simply remain in the same (local) area.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for taking the time to post under this question. It's great that you want to help. However, this answer doesn't really seem to be a full answer. When answering it's best, in the case of [tag:single-word-requests], to give a good explanation why the word you're suggesting is a good one. If necessary quote and reference a dictionary.